# What does this tag do?

Tags: html, angularjs

I have been learning how to read other people's code and when ever I see something like this `<meganav-item item="item" ng-repeat="item in website.nav.primary"></meganav-item>` I get stuck.

I have a basic understand of angular, but the problem is the `<meganav>` tag. I do not know what this is..I have done a Google search, but nothing useful is showing.

**Update**

I have managed to locate the file of the `<meganav>` element. After following the instructions from the links that you guys have provided, it led me to a file named "MegaNavItem.js". Here is the code:

```
window.tcoStore.directive('meganavItem', ['$timeout','transport', function($timeout,transport) {
    var lockTimeout = false;
    var meganavLocks = transport.getModel('meganavLocks', {lock : false});
    var clear = function (){
        if(meganavLocks.timeout){
            $timeout.cancel(meganavLocks.timeout);
        }
    }
    var action = function(callback, time) {
        if(meganavLocks.lock){
            return;
        }
        clear();
        meganavLocks.timeout = $timeout(callback, time);
    }
    var dropLock = function(callback, time) {
        meganavLocks.lock = false;
    }
    return {
        restrict : 'E',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl : '/page/header/meganav/item.html',
        scope : {
            item : '=',
            clickOnly : '@',
            delayIn : '@',
            delayOut : '@'
        },
        link : function($scope, elem, attrs){
            if(!$scope.clickOnly){
                $scope.delayInValue = parseInt($scope.delayIn || 300,10);
                $scope.delayOutValue = parseInt($scope.delayOut || 500,10);

                elem.on('mouseenter', $scope.showDelayed);
                if($scope.delayOutValue > 0){
                    elem.on('mouseleave', $scope.hideDelayed);
                }
            }
        },
        controller: ['$scope', '$timeout', 'transport', '$location' ,
            function($scope, $timeout, transport,$location) {

            // When $location changes ...
            $scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function() {
                $scope.hide(true);

                $scope.isActive = !_.isUndefined($scope.item.link) && ($scope.item.link.replace(/\/+$/,'') == $location.path().replace(/\/+$/,''));
            });

            $scope.loadSubmenu =0;

            //  tranposrt model accessable by other items
            var meganavVisibleModel = transport.getModel('meganavActive');
            var meganavVisibleModelId = $scope.item.$$hashKey;
            meganavVisibleModel[meganavVisibleModelId] = false;

            // hide and show funs
            $scope.hide  = function(forceFullClose){
                clear();
                meganavVisibleModel[meganavVisibleModelId] = false;
                if(forceFullClose) {
                    meganavLocks.lock = true;
                    $timeout.cancel(lockTimeout);
                    lockTimeout = $timeout(dropLock, 1000);
                }
            };


            $scope.hideDelayed = function (delay) {
                action($scope.hide, _.isNumber(delay) ? delay : $scope.delayOutValue);
            };

            $scope.show  = function(){
                if(meganavLocks.lock){
                    return;
                }
                clear();
                $scope.loadSubmenu = 1;
                for(var i in meganavVisibleModel){
                    meganavVisibleModel[i] = (meganavVisibleModelId == i);
                }
            };

            $scope.showDelayed = function (delay) {
                action($scope.show, _.isNumber(delay) ? delay : $scope.delayInValue);
            };

            $scope.$watch(function(){
                $scope.visible = meganavVisibleModel[meganavVisibleModelId];
            });


            // first touch click, second touch go to link
            $scope.touch = function($event, path){
                if(!$scope.visible) {
                    //$event.preventDefault();
                    $scope.show();
                }else if(tco.empty(path)) {
                    $scope.hide();
                } else {
                    if(path.match(/^https?:/)){
                        window.location.href = path;
                    }else{
                        $location.path(path);
                    }
                }
            }

        }]
    }
}]);
```

And this file led me to another file named item.html. The code :

```
<li class="header--menu__item my-repeat-animation" ng-class="{ 'is-active': isActive, open : visible && item.groups.length}" off-click="hide()" >
    <a ng-if=":: item.groups.length"
        ng-class="{active: item.active}"
        class="header--menu__item--link has-children"
        ng-click="show()"
        title="{{::item.name}}">
        {{::item.name}}
    </a>
    <a ng-if=":: !item.groups.length"
       class="header--menu__item--link"
       href="{{::item.link}}"
       title="{{::item.name}}">
        {{::item.name}}
    </a>

    <div class="header-menu-dropdown ng-hide" ng-show="visible" ng-if=":: item.groups.length">
        <ul class="header-menu-dropdown__meganavGroup">
            <li ng-repeat="meganavGroup in item.groups" class="header--menu-group">
                <span class="meganav--group--name">{{::meganavGroup.name}}</span>
                <ul class="meganav--group--items">
                    <li ng-repeat="groupItem in meganavGroup.items">
                        <a href="{{::groupItem.link}}">{{::groupItem.name}}</a>
                        <span class="icon"></span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="header-menu-offers" ng-repeat="offer in item.offers">
                <a href="{{::offer.offer_link}}" class="placeholder">
                    <img tco-image="offer.offer_image" crop="3" alt="{{::offer.offer_name}}" />
                </a>
                <span class="offer-name">{{::offer.offer_name}}</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="header-menu-message" ng-bind-html="item.message"></div>
    </div>
</li>
```

My issue is now that I cannot make out what where to find {{::item.name}}, which is the thing that I want to change. What technique can I use to find {{::item.name}}?

Sorry for all the noob questions! Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: It means whatever the author of `meganavItem` intends it to mean. No, it's not a standard tag. It's some custom directive. Search the project for "meganavItem".

Comment: This is an angularjs directive. You can write as many custom directives in a project as you want.

Comment: It's a custom tag for a custom angular directive named *"meganavItem"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Angular it is possible to build your own HTML element. You won't find any information about this element because it doesn't exist. The developer has created that on its own and handles the content inside a module. Have a look at http://www.aleaiactaest.ch/2012/07/29/build-your-own-html-element-with-angular/ for more information.

Hope this helps, Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

As i've noticed it's **Angular** App, so probably there are defined an **directive** which is called `meganavItem`. See [Angular Directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) for more information, you have to  find  definition of that directive and discover what is html layout  and logic lives under `<meganav-item>`. However if there are no directive with defined name.

Also it may be separate registered element, see ["Custom Elements
"](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/?redirect_from_locale=ru)article of how it's done and it would be more easy for you to find out how it works ( if it registered in that way...)